# Get Document FileRef value from SharePoint App Workflow

Tags: workflow, app

I am trying to get the document URL from a document in a document library from SharePoint App Workflow.

I know the column name is FileRef but when I add a LookupSPListItem, I do not have FileRef listed.

I know how to do this in CSOM and [designer](https://plumsail.com/blog/2014/08/how-to-work-with-dictionaries-in-sharepoint-2013-and-office-365-workflow/)

I have tried manually typing FileRef and have look at most (if not all) other Columns listed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I have to manually load columns as per [this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4476b650-7a1e-474c-a2a4-349fd010c4bc/how-to-read-the-name-field-from-document-library-in-workflow?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

I managed to get file name by adding

```
  new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<string> { "FileLeafRef" }
```

to SPGetListItem properties

Does not work on FileRef though so I need to get add library URL to it

Answer (score 0):

Change your view fields like this below,

```
     <View Scope="RecursiveAll">
 <ViewFields>        
      <FieldRef Name="FileRef"/>
     <FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef"/>
   </ViewFields>
```

Try this link,https://plumsail.com/blog/2014/06/how-to-move-documents-using-workflow-in-sharepoint-2013-and-office-365/

Comment: That is from designer not visual studio and the same link in my post

Comment: then you have to frame the url using designer.

Comment: It is a SharePoint App